# Bijection proof and option type

Tags: coq

I'm learning Coq and I've stumbled upon an exercise asking to create functions for the option type to/from bool and nat (i.e., bool to/from option X, nat to option nat), and then prove they commute. I can easily prove by induction on bool/nat, but I can't seem to make it work for the option type. The main problem in the bool question that I ran into is that, at some point, the goal is to prove that:

```
a : nat_iter 1 option Empty_set
============================
Some None = Some a
```

however, I don't know tell it the only possibility for `nat_iter 1 option Empty_set` is to be `None` (I have a lemma proving that, but can't rewrite `a`).

With the nat one, I don't think there is a bijection between nat and option nat, since I cannot prove that, given `fromNat (toNat x) = x`, `Some 0 = None`. Maybe there's a way to define `toNat` that makes this work.

```
Definition fromBool (b : bool) : fin 2 :=
  match b with
  | true => Some None
  | false => None
  end.

Definition toBool (x : fin 2) : bool :=
  match x with
  | None => false
  | Some _ => true
  end.

Lemma bool_fin b :
  toBool (fromBool b) = b.
Proof. induction b ; reflexivity. Qed.

Lemma fin_bool x :
  fromBool (toBool x) = x.
Proof. induction x ; simpl. Abort.

Definition fromNat (n : nat) : option nat :=
  match n with
  | 0 => None
  | S n => Some (S n)
  end.

Definition toNat (n : option nat) : nat :=
  match n with
  | None => 0
  | Some x => x
  end.

Lemma nat_option x :
  toNat (fromNat x) = x.
Proof. induction x ; reflexivity. Qed.

Lemma option_nat x :
  fromNat (toNat x) = x.
Proof. induction x. Abort.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well, `fun n:nat => match n with | O => None | S m => Some m end` is a bijection `nat -> option nat` with inverse `fun x:option nat => match x with | None => O | Some n => S n end`.

Comment: @DanielSchepler thanks, I managed to solve the nat question with your help.

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel   :)

Comment: You don't need induction to prove `option_nat` and `nat_option` lemmas, `destruct` would suffice.